# Link Bower Library in Sails.js project

Tags: angularjs, sails.js, asset-pipeline

I have been following along this tutorial: https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-todo-app-using-sailsjs-and-angularjs#front-end

and when I got to the end, the home page was the default sails one. I looked at the console, and found the error:

```
angular not defined
```

Based on what I'm seeing, my bower installation went to

```
/assets/library
```

not

```
/bower_components/...
```

The tutorial says to use this type of pipeline file:

```
var cssFilesToInject = [
'bower_components/bootswatch/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
'styles/**/*.css'
];
var jsFilesToInject = [
  'js/dependencies/sails.io.js',
  '/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
  '/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
  '/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
  '/bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js',
  '/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/boostrap.js',
  'js/dependencies/**/*.js',

  'js/**/*.js'
  ];

var templateFilesToInject = [
'templates/*.html'
];

module.exports.cssFilesToInject = cssFilesToInject.map(function(path) {
  return '.tmp/public/' + path;
});
module.exports.jsFilesToInject = jsFilesToInject.map(function(path) {
  return '.tmp/public/' + path;
});
module.exports.templateFilesToInject = templateFilesToInject.map(function(path) {
  return 'assets/' + path;
});
```

Mine currently looks like this:

```
/**
 * grunt/pipeline.js
 *
 * The order in which your css, javascript, and template files should be
 * compiled and linked from your views and static HTML files.
 *
 * (Note that you can take advantage of Grunt-style wildcard/glob/splat expressions
 * for matching multiple files, and the ! prefix for excluding files.)
 */

// Path to public folder
var tmpPath = '.tmp/public/';

// CSS files to inject in order
//
// (if you're using LESS with the built-in default config, you'll want
//  to change `assets/styles/importer.less` instead.)
var cssFilesToInject = [

  'styles/**/*.css'
];


// Client-side javascript files to inject in order
// (uses Grunt-style wildcard/glob/splat expressions)
var jsFilesToInject = [

  // Load sails.io before everything else
  'js/dependencies/sails.io.js',
  // Dependencies like jQuery, or Angular are brought in here
  'js/dependencies/**/*.js',
  // All of the rest of your client-side js files
  // will be injected here in no particular order.
  'js/**/*.js',

  // Use the "exclude" operator to ignore files
  // '!js/ignore/these/files/*.js'
];


// Client-side HTML templates are injected using the sources below
// The ordering of these templates shouldn't matter.
// (uses Grunt-style wildcard/glob/splat expressions)
//
// By default, Sails uses JST templates and precompiles them into
// functions for you.  If you want to use jade, handlebars, dust, etc.,
// with the linker, no problem-- you'll just want to make sure the precompiled
// templates get spit out to the same file.  Be sure and check out `tasks/README.md`
// for information on customizing and installing new tasks.
var templateFilesToInject = [
  'templates/**/*.html'
];


// module.exports.cssFilesToInject = cssFilesToInject.map(function(path) {
//   return '.tmp/public/' + path;
// });
// module.exports.jsFilesToInject = jsFilesToInject.map(function(path) {
//   return '.tmp/public/' + path;
// });
// module.exports.templateFilesToInject = templateFilesToInject.map(function(path) {
//   return 'assets/' + path;
// });


// Prefix relative paths to source files so they point to the proper locations
// (i.e. where the other Grunt tasks spit them out, or in some cases, where
// they reside in the first place)
module.exports.cssFilesToInject = cssFilesToInject.map(transformPath);
module.exports.jsFilesToInject = jsFilesToInject.map(transformPath);
module.exports.templateFilesToInject = templateFilesToInject.map(transformPath);

// Transform paths relative to the "assets" folder to be relative to the public
// folder, preserving "exclude" operators.
function transformPath(path) {
  return (path.substring(0,1) == '!') ? ('!' + tmpPath + path.substring(1)) : (tmpPath + path);
}
```

**Can I somehow include everything in the library directory without naming each file explicitly?**

The directory currently looks like:

```
\library
|--\angular
|--\angular-bootstrap
|--\bootstrap
...etc
```

Comment: You should be able to put `library/**/*.js`.

Comment: Would that catch `/library/bootstrap/dist/js/boostrap.js` as well?

Comment: Yes. Try it out. the `/**/` is a wild-card for folders _and_ nested folders. Just one level deep would be `library/*/*.js`

Comment: It seems to list out a number of times `angular is not defined` like its trying to load the libraries out of order or something?

Comment: Run `sails lift` and try to see if the paths are accessible, e.g. `http://localhost:8080/library/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js`.

Comment: Ugh, well, I got it to work by putting the paths in, and putting it in the order they specified: `library/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js` etc, but doing it "automatically" didn't work.